# Detect Active Directory domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, active-directory

I'm trying to find out if it's possible to detect whether a user is visiting the site from a given domain (network domain not website domain) for example is the machine on the `businessname.local` domain.

I currently implement `Forms` Authentication for the website which is perfectly suitable.  I am looking at implementing an `Intranet` site for the company.

This would be a completely separate project from the primary site.  My goal is to detect that a users computer is on the domain and present them with the option to visit the `Intranet` and if they wish to do so then I would redirect the user.

Is this possible?

EDIT:

Just for clarification.  I'm not asking about implementing Active-Directory Authentication for the `Intranet` site (I know how to do this).  I'm simply wondering if I a method exists to detect the domain and offer to redirect if it's applicable for a given user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with to solve the issue was to create a `Controller` on the intranet site that was simply used to return a `true` or `false` depending on Active Directory authentication for the machine accessing it.

The intended result was only to display the option of a redirect...not to display actual content so I don't believe this opens up any security issues (please correct me if I'm wrong).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get('URL-to-test-controller', function (data) {
        if ($.trim(data) === "true") {
            if (askAboutRedirect()) {
                window.location = "intranetaddress";
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Due to the cross-domain issues the `Controller` providing the result has the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header set...

```
Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "requesting server");
```

As per [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-header)

Answer (score 0):

Dectecting whether the user is within a domain isn't too bad.  Use this line of code:

```
HttpContext.User.Identity.Name
```

From that, you'll get something like this:  domain\username.  Just manipulate the string to look at the domain and from there offer to redirect.  It would be easy enough to place within a Controller, like in an index page, etc.

Comment: This works if the application is setup FOR Active Director/Domain authentication.  It does little however for detecting if the user is ON a domain currently.

Comment: Actually, no you don't.  I have a site that uses a combination of forms and windows authentication.  I do a check based on HttpContext.User.Identity.Name to see if their username is within my forms security.  If not, they need to register.  It also lets me see what domain they're on.

Comment: The site that I'm wanting to detect this from is only configured for forms authentication and is not enabled for Windows Authentication.  Quite frankly the line of code above does little in this scenario for my intended result.  If the user isn't logged in there is no return value.  What I'm wanting my not be possible in the current configuration (and if so that's fine), but this is not the solution to the issue I have.